# Do Chromium or Manganese supplements have any benefits?

Tags: nutritional-supplements

Louie Helm of [Rockstar Research Magazine](http://rockstarresearch.com/) blog [argues that](http://rockstarresearch.com/most-multivitamins-have-these-2-toxic-minerals-in-them/) that the human body doesn't need Chromium nor Manganese and, therefore, there is no need to have them in multivitamin supplements.

> This leaves Chromium and Manganese as the most commonly recommended minerals that still make their way into most multivitamins despite having no proposed mechanisms of action.

Is that an accurate reflection of the current science?

Comment: My understanding is that chromium deficiency problems cropped up with some patients on enteral formulas.

Comment: Note: He *does* cite some peer-reviewed research for Cr: [Chromium is not an essential trace element for mammals: effects of a “low-chromium” diet](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00775-010-0734-y). The formatting makes it a bit obscure to find (click on "Original Story").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Chromium:

> Despite popular claims in nutritional literature, there is no
> definitive evidence that chromium (Cr) is an essential element for
> human or animal nutrition.

- *2012 - [Chromium - biological relevance](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781119951438.eibc0040.pub2/abstract;jsessionid=63E6EEECFA45C1AFB98A793E782D86B3.f01t01?systemMessage=Wiley%20Online%20Library%20will%20be%20disrupted%20on%20the%2018th%20October%20from%2010%3A00%20BST%20%2805%3A00%20EDT%29%20for%20essential%20maintenance%20for%20approximately%20two%20hours%20as%20we%20make%20upgrades%20to%20improve%20our%20services%20to%20you&userIsAuthenticated=false&deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=)*

> Chromium plays a role in insulin physiology, and severe chromium
> deficiency can lead to insulin resistance. Chromium supplementation
> may be beneficial in rare cases of prolonged total parental nutrition
> when standard chromium supplementation is lacking[6]. Despite the lack
> of sufficient evidence that chromium supplementation improves glycemic
> control[28,29], chromium is still widely marketed as an effective
> supplement for improving glycemic control in patients with type 2
> diabetes.

- *2014 - [Chromium does not belong in the diabetes treatment arsenal: Current evidence and future perspectives](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3990317/)*

> Based on the animal studies, our results suggest that blood Cr(III)
> concentrations as high as 480–580 μg/L are not associated with any
> responses. For each of the three health endpoints considered in this
> analysis (hematological, hepatic, and renal) no adverse effects were
> observed below 3,700 μg/L. Some hematological responses were observed
> at 3,700 μg/L, and adverse effects clearly occurred at 7,500 μg/L.
> These findings can be used to assess potential health risks to
> individuals with elevated blood Cr(III) concentrations.

- *2014 - [Correlation of blood Cr(III) and adverse health effects: Application of PBPK modeling to determine non-toxic blood concentrations](http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.3109/10408444.2014.926472)*

Chromium can play an important role in human physiology, but if you do not have severe chromium deficiency (which is rare) you should not consume chromium nutritions, because you don't need it, and because it can cause hepatic and renal damage.

## Manganese:

> Manganese superoxide dismutase (MnSOD) is a critical component of the
> antioxidant system tasked with protecting the oxidant-sensitive
> mitochondrial compartment from oxidative stress. Since global knockout
> of MnSOD results in significant cardiac and neuronal damage leading to
> early postnatal lethality, this approach has limited use for studying
> the mechanisms of oxidant stress and the development of disease in
> specific tissues lacking MnSOD.

- *from [The Use of the Cre/loxP System to Study Oxidative Stress in Tissue-Specific Manganese Superoxide Dismutase Knockout Models](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/ars.2013.5293)*

> For humans manganese is both an essential trace element and, at higher
> doses, a toxic metal. Due to the ubiquitous occurrence of manganese in
> foodstuff, in industrial countries daily dietary uptake is higher as
> compared to the estimated daily requirement. Therefore manganese
> deficiency is extremely rare. In contrast chronic manganese toxicity,
> affecting primarily the central nervous system, is more prevalent.
> Thus manganese occupational and dietary overexposure has been shown to
> cause progressive, permanent, neurodegenerative damage, resulting in
> syndromes similar to idiopathic Parkinson's disease.
> To date modes of manganese neurotoxic action are poorly understood and
> in most studies oxidative stress is postulated as the underlying
> mechanism. The present study searched on the cellular level for a
> molecular mechanism behind manganese-induced neurotoxicity and
> investigated bioavailability, cytotoxicity and genotoxicity of MnCl2,
> as well as its impact on the DNA damage response in human cells (HeLa
> S3) in culture.

- *from [Manganese inhibits poly(ADP-ribosyl)ation in human cells: a possible mechanism behind manganese-induced toxicity?](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2010/em/c0em00252f#!divAbstract)*

Manganese certainly plays an important role in human physiology, but if you don't have manganese deficiency (which is rare either), then you should not consume manganese nutritions, because too much manganese can cause neural damage. It has a small genotoxicity either, so huge amounts in long term may cause cancer, but I guess you would die before that because of the the neural damage. ;-)